# How to persist scheduled jobs using APScheduler until they finish completely?

Tags: python, jobs, apscheduler

I'm using [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with Python 2.7.6. I'm using [BlockingScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler) to store scheduled jobs and [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as persistent database.

I want to schedule jobs and guarantee that they finish (function reach last line). Everything is working fine, but I see that when a job is started, it's removed from the database, even when the job did not finish the entire method.

Note: Obviously, I developed jobs that do not have state and can be re-executed in next program executions. This should be not an issue to be discussed in this question.

**What is the best way to persist a job until the complete function/method is executed using APScheduler?**

Comment: For what purpose do you need this? APScheduler does not have any "retry" functionality so jobs that have no next run times left are automatically removed from the store.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm as I said, I need to guarantee the job is executed completely, even if the program crashes or is interrupted. I'm working in solution just now.

Comment: This would indeed need a design change in the scheduler.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm yes, probably my requirement does not fit in the library design...

Comment: Your requirement is not unreasonable. I will take this under advisement and will see if it's feasible to add to a future release.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm any features to solve this in 2018? :)

Comment: Add a feature request in the issue tracker. It would also be helpful to point to an existing implementation of this.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm done: https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and was able to resolve it using Background Scheduler instead of blocking scheduler.